# Input of RNN model layer how it works?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I don't understand input of RNN model. Why it show None before node size every layer. Why it is (None,1) (None,12)

This is my code.

```
K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a RNN, it's just a fully connected network (FC or Dense).

The first dimension of every tensor in a Keras network is the `batch_size`, which represents the number of "samples" or "examples" you are passing to the model. The value is `None` because this dimension is not fixed, you can have batches of any size you want.